# Test (pytest) Being Skipped While Using Jenkins, But Not Run Directly

Tags: python, jenkins, pytest

I am using pytest for testing on a function, but it seem to be having an issue executing only when running on/with Jenkins. It runs fine if I directly execute the command on the Jenkins machine though.

I have the below functions...

This code runs fine on my local, and after running on Jenkins, if I copy and paste the actual command (cmd) executed on Jenkins, it also works fine. But when Jenkins executes it as a job. The test gets skipped. I tried a simple test function where it just takes in the `get_asset` function and print out the return, it returns everything correctly. So I am not sure what I am missing and why test only being skipped while running as Jenkins job.

**Helper Function**

```py
def get_asset() -> list[PathLike]:
    """Return list of asset(s)"""
    asset_list = []
    for asset in get_file_list(CURRENT_MODULE_PATH / 'asset'):
        # get_file_list return generator
        if 'need_to_skip_asset' in str(asset):
            continue
        asset_list.append(asset)

    return asset_list
```

**Test Function**

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('asset', get_asset())
def test_app_launch_asset(app_binary, asset):
    """Test Application Function"""

    print(f'Application: {app_binary}')
    print(f'Asset: {asset}')

    # Run `cmd`
    applib.execute(
        cmd=[str(app_binary), str(asset)],
        timeout=15,
    )
```

Comment: Please add the details of your pipeline (settings and code) and execution environment to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after sometime of debugging, I finally figured what was the issue. It is not just Jenkins, but a combination of Jenkins and `pytest`.

It basically come to the following points:

- The `pytest` module execute collection before executing the fixture and any helper function for the test. This cause `get_asset` function return in correct value only when running on Jenkins job due to next point.
- The Jenkins job does workspace clean before execution of the test. This cause manual test run after the job errored out to still keeping the artifact resource in workspace, so it doesn't throw any error.

**Solution:**

- For the `pytest` module, it comes with `pytest_configure` and `pytest_sessionstart`, execute file retrieval in either method. This way if you need to dynamically list a directory for file, it will be accounted for.

This might be a niche case, but sharing reference.